# mssql_fetch_object text character limit?

Tags: php, sql, fetch

I'm fetching some data from an MSSQL table using the mssql_fetch_object, but the text appears to cut off on the page.

The data is all there in the table, but it seems to cut off in the view page.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and perhaps knows of a workaround? Here is my code;

```
<?php include('includes/session.php');
$query = "SELECT content FROM pages WHERE id = '11'";
$result = mssql_query($query);
$page = mssql_fetch_object($result);
?>

<div id="leftcol">
<?php echo stripslashes($page->content) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why stripslashes? Data comes out of the database raw, all you have to do to put it on the page is htmlspecialchars() it (assuming it's text and not already HTML).

Comment: @bobince The content has some formatting in it as we are using the CK Editor. However, the content still seems to get cut off in  the view page even when we don't use stripslashes. :S

Comment: I would suggest doing a VAR_DUMP() to see whats being returned

echo var_dump($page->content);

Comment: Hey Phill, the VAR_DUMP() returned string(4096) " to the end of the initial text, cutting the text off in the word 'to'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with using mssql in php, but I just tried an example using mysql without problem.

This looks suspicious to me

> VAR_DUMP() returned string(4096)

so I did some googling and found this link

http://www.bram.us/2007/07/05/my-dotd-ms-sql-vs-php-4096-is-the-default-limit/

It suggests to change mssql.textlimit and mssql.textsize to 1048576 (which is 2ˆ20) in your php.ini as the default is 4096. Hope that helps.

php.ini

```
  ; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
  mssql.textlimit = 1048576
  ; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
  mssql.textsize = 1048576
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it a VARCHAR field? http://docs.php.net/mssql_field_length says:

> Note: Note to Windows Users
> Due to a limitation in the underlying API used by PHP (MS DBLib C API), the length of VARCHAR fields is limited to 255. If you need to store more data, use a TEXT field instead.

Comment: @VolkerK The data type is TEXT, which is odd why the characters are being cut off. :S

Answer (score 0):

try a strlen() on the data and compare the length to the data within the database. It should give you some indication of where the problem is (db or php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
mssql.textlimit = 10000000
mssql.textsize  = 10000000
```

in your php.ini or set it with `ini_set('mssql.textlimi', 10000000);`

Answer (score 0):

I have silimar issue when i use PHP to direct connect to MS SQL, and data type Varchar only retrieve up to 255 charactors.  the issue solve by convert the data type to text under the query, and it works for now.

eg:

before

select desc from table1

after

select convert(text, desc) as desc from table1